# Good way to check if a view is pressed

Tags: android, optimization, multi-touch

I'm trying to manage a multi task app that works with many buttons.

For this purpose i made this function:

```
public boolean isTouched(View view, MotionEvent event) {
    boolean touched = false;
    int count = event.getPointerCount();

    int[] location = { 0, 0 };
    view.getLocationOnScreen(location);
    Point min = new Point(location[0], location[1]);
    Point max = new Point(min.x + view.getWidth(), min.y + view.getHeight());

    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {


        int rawX = (int) event.getX(i);
        int rawY = (int) event.getY(i);
        if(rawX>=min.x && rawX<=max.x && rawY>=min.y && rawY<=max.y){
            //Log.d("mylog", "***Found a view: " + v.getId());
            touched = true;
            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) touched = false;
        }
    }
    return touched;
    }
```

And the function override of the activity that intercept onTouchEvent and manage two ImageView

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent (MotionEvent event) {

    if (isTouched(button1,event)) {
        // it is pressed
        if ((Integer)button1.getTag() == 0) {  // but before wasn't pressed
            mp1.start();
            button1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.happy_on);
            button1.setTag(1);

            // start music 1
        }
    } else {
        // it isn't pressed
        if ((Integer)button1.getTag() == 1) {   // and before it was pressed
            mp1.stop();
            try {
                mp1.prepare();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace(); 
            }  catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                Log.e("hb","illegal state exception mp2") ;
                mp1= MediaPlayer.create(getBaseContext(), R.raw.female01) ;

            }

            button1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.happy_off);
            button1.setTag(0);
            // stop music 1
        }
    }

         if (isTouched(button2,event)) {
             // it is pressed
             if ((Integer)button2.getTag() == 0) {  // but before wasn't pressed
                 mp2.start();

                 button2.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.to_on);
                 button2.setTag(1);
                 // start music 2
             }

         } else {
             // it isn't pressed
             if ((Integer)button2.getTag() == 1) {   // and before it was pressed
                 mp2.stop();
                 try {
                     mp2.prepare();
                 } catch (IOException e) {
                     e.printStackTrace(); 
                 } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                     Log.e("hb","illegal state exception mp2") ;
                     mp2= MediaPlayer.create(getBaseContext(), R.raw.female02) ;                     }

                 button2.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.to_off);
                 button2.setTag(0);
                 // stop music 1
             }
         }

    return false;

    }
```

Buttons (i used imageview) are pressed like a piano keyboard: you can pass it over with one, two finger and a async action starts when the pointer enter in the view. At event_up or pointer leave the button, action stop.

It works, but it is a very slow method: it is flooded by many action_move events.

Can anybody know a method to optimize this way of multi touch managing?

EDIT: mp1 and mp2 are mp3 mediaplayer objects. When i'm passing from a button to another button without release the pointer it works, but there is a some-milliseconds gap that make the melody jump. The effect i would to make is like the keyboard of a piano, without gaps.

I think that the gap is produced for the weight of the function isTouched. How can I reduce this weigth?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You should probably use regular `Button`s with multiple state drawables instead of `ImageView` and then use `setOnClickListener(...)` or define `android:onclick` in XML. I think the problem you're currently facing is just the first facet of a flawed design decision you have made.

Comment: Jon: i made this decision because Android doesn't natively support multi touch buttons and multiple focus. Do you know apps like piano keyboard ? Is impossible to have an effect like this using onClickListener or Buttons.